# Examine convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}z^{n(n+1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Consider the (complex) power series  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}z^{n(n+1)}$$

Show that the radius of convergence is $1$ and examine convergence for $z = 1,-1,i$.

**Source problem**: Conway's "functions of one complex variable".

Attempt:

For $z=1$, we get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n/n$ which converges by the alternating series test.

For $z=-1$, we get $$\sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{(-1)^{n+n(n+1)}}{n}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n^2}}{n}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$ which is the same series as the previous case.

For $z=i$, we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} i^{n(n+1)}$$

How can I deduce if this series converges/diverges? I tried ratio and root test but they both give limit $1$, so they do not apply. What other test can I use or how can I manipulate this expression in something I can work with?

If it follows that we have divergence for this value $z=i$, then it will also automatically follow that the convergence radius is $1$.

Comment: The period is $4$ here so check $1,2,3,4$

Comment: Why do you think that the ratio and root test "do not apply"?

Comment: How about $z = e^{it}$ for rational and irrational $t$?

Comment: You need to learn how to apply the root and ratio tests *correctly* to get the radius of convergence.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't understand your comment. The ratio and root test give limit $1$, and thus are inconclusive. This is supported by WA: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%3D1+to+infinity+%28-1%29%5En%2Fn+i%5E%28n%28n%2B1%29%29

Comment: Not true. That's for applying the ratio/root test to a series of *numbers*, not a series of *functions*. Keep the powers of $z$ in your computation ...

Comment: I applied it for $z=i$, so I can apply it. I.e. I applied ratio test to $\sum a_n$ with $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} i^{n(n+1)}$ and this gave limit $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $\bigl((-1)^ni^{n(n+1)}\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is simply the sequence$$1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1,\ldots$$Since the partial sums of this sequence are bounded, and since the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is monotonic and converges to $0$, your series converges, by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).